# Memsql-list shows newly added leaf node in DISCONNECTED state

Tags: sql, installation, singlestore

I added a new leaf node(10.162.140.63) using memsql-ops UI, but the node is disconnected from the cluster.
Existing leaf node (10.162.141.12) works correctly.

```
$ memsql-ops memsql-list
ID      Agent Id Process State Cluster State  Role Host     Port Version
DB381ED A57780e  RUNNING CONNECTED     MASTER 10.162.141.11 3306 7.1.2
4BB555C A20f163  RUNNING CONNECTED     LEAF   10.162.141.12 3306 7.1.2
C2C2080 A9af13d  RUNNING DISCONNECTED  LEAF   10.162.140.63 3306 7.1.2


 
$ memsql-ops agent-list
ID      Host          Port Role     State  Version
A57780e 10.162.141.11 9000 PRIMARY  ONLINE 6.7.8
A20f163 10.162.141.12 9000 FOLLOWER ONLINE 6.7.8
A9af13d 10.162.140.63 9000 FOLLOWER ONLINE 6.7.8
```

Attaching screenshot from memsql ops UI. Any help would be highly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d recommend upgrading to a new engine release and also upgrading to SingleStore tools 1. Memsql-ops is not supported any longer.

https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.6/en/user-and-cluster-administration/cluster-management-with-tools/singlestore-tools-overview.html?action=version-change